# Smart Contract Deployment through React JS

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereumj

I have deployed multiple contracts using Truffle and Hardhat from a NodeJS project, but I wanted to know if there is a way to deploy smart contracts from ReactJS?

Comment: You can do it, the same way you did on truffle/hardhat, except that the provider will be your Ethereum provider (window.ethereum compatible EIP1193)

Comment: What plugin/library should I use for this @AdamBoudjemaa?

Comment: I'm using `ethers.js` but you can use anything

Comment: `ethers.js` does the job. Thank you @AdamBoudjemaa

Answer (score 0):

There is, but this is like making a website without a JS framework. You would have to do everything manually when you could always just use Truffle or Hardhat. I don't advise doing this unless you understand Truffle or HH at a VERY intimate level.

Comment: Can you please tell me, in brief, how is this possible?

Comment: Well, that was the brief version of it. You are basically electing to manually use every package that HardHat automatically brings in.